# Fixing a found Acer desktop tower : power supply issue?

Tags: power-supply, shutdown, desktop-computer, acer-aspire

I found in the street the tower of an ACER desktop computer. Having some free time and willing to learn more on how to fix hardware issues, my plan is to repair it.

[ACER-Aspire-X3810](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNEza.jpg)

when powering it on, the fan starts, the starting light lights up... 3 sec then it shuts down, and 3 sec later it tries automatically to start again but shuts down... etc.

I opened it and cleaned the dust, it does not smell like burnt, 
but I suspect an issue with the power supply:

[inside-view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rArP1.jpg)

Have anyone of you met a similar issue?

Comment: More info: no capacitors look burst, the fan works

Comment: Try reseating the CPU amd heatsink fan, amd perhaps replace the thermal compound and try again.

Comment: Sounds like the CPU or the motherboard is dead.  hope you don't plan to use that Windows 7 key....

Comment: I just saw that the memory modules are gone, looks like the previous owner took them. Peter, what do you mean by "reseating the CPU"?

Answer (score 0):

From what you last posted, I am assuming that you have determined that the issue is being caused by the lack of RAM, most likely.

Reseating is basically just unplugging and re-plugging the connections so that you are positive they are properly secured \ not damaged. Since you found this PC, if you didn't have any indication regarding its failure, that would be a step you would take early on to insure nothing became dislodged, etc.

It's very likely to be running Windows and therefore will not run without RAM. Try to replace RAM if possible, and then go from there. If it doesn't start up, try replacing the battery affixed to the Motherboard.